# Support for right-to-left with Arabic characters

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-ce, arabic

I'm currently working on adding Arabic support into a product which is running a .Net Compact Framework application on top of Windows CE 5.0. Arabic support has been added into the OS and the .Net application is aware of the AR-sa locale. Arabic translations for the UI elements are stored in a resource file, in which they are the correct way round and read correctly according to one of my colleagues. When the application runs, it looks like all the characters are reversed which makes it look like either the OS or the application is mirroring them to give the RTL support. When we reverse the strings in the resource file, it still appears the same.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could possibly be going wrong and if there is any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting RTL behavior in any control?  In the CF, some controls will give RTL, some won't.  Daniel Moth [blogged a workaround for those that don't](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/progress-on-rtl.aspx) (using CE 5.0 as well).

Is your entire OS set up as RTL right now (i.e. are system dialogs, etc showing RTL, or still LTR)? If the system isn't already doing RTL, then you need to verify support and that your OS locale is set since `Control.RightToLeft` isn't supported.  It's possible that you might use the P/Invokes Daniel outlines (link above) to force controls into RTL when the system isn't.

Comment: In the end I have solved this issue. I came across an article on CodeProject which detailed how to get characters displaying correctly in Win Phone 7 (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383484/Arabic-Controls-in-Window-phone-7) which proved to be useful. Using the code snippets on this page I now 'Arabize' text to make it look right and all looks good. Thanks.